# Vim: Change syntax highlight on-demand

Tags: html, vim, highlighting

I have some HTML files with arbitrary extension.

I would like to know if it's possible to order `vim` to change the highlight with a command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force syntax highlighting for a language by setting `syntax`:

```
:set syntax=html
```

If you'd also like to load filetype-specific settings, you should set `filetype` instead. This is probably what you want:

```
:set filetype=html
```

Since you mention you're editing more than one such file, you can automatically set the filetype for a given extension using `autocmd`:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.<extension> setlocal filetype=html
```

You can also have this persist into future sessions by placing it in your `vimrc`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want just to tell vim that the file you are editing is written in html? Use a command `:set filetype=html` or just `:set ft=html`.